# I disabled a form control in angular6, but it also can be edit

Tags: angular, forms, controls

I have disabled the control in a form in angular6, the style is disabled, but it can be edit, i do not know why!

```ts
this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [name, [Validators.required], [this.businessService.uniquenessValidator('name', this.tableData, id)]],
    type: [{value: type, disabled: true}, []],
});

if (hasNoAuth) {
    this.validateForm.controls['name'].disable();
}
```

[image]

I hope it can not be edit, but it can be edit!

Answer (score 0):

You can put in your input a propraty

```
[disabled]="hasNoAuth"
```

That will works